# Media query not changing margin

Tags: html, css

I have css that should make the div margin go to 10% if the screen is 1920px wide or less, and 20% margin-left if the screen width is any higher. For some reason though, the media query is not working. Here is the code for it. Thanks!

```
.about-me-header{
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 20%;
    height: 20%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1920){
    .about-me-header{
        margin-left: 10%;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to mention px like `max-width: 1920px` in media query `max-width` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the type of length. Like `1920px`

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1920px){
    .about-me-header{
        margin-left: 10%;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I didn't realize I forgot to add `px`.